# Issues with @slf4j generation

Tags: java, lombok

I have a maven project with lombok (1.18.4) dependency. However, @slf4j generates LOGGER variable instead of the log variable. This issue happens while building with maven (cli or via Intellij)

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
...

@SuppressFBWarnings(
        justification = "generated code"
    )
    @Generated
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CBStatus.class);
```

Has anyone encounter this issue before??

Also, does anyone know which class expands the lombok annotations?

Comment: The annotation has a name argument where you can override the default name 'log'. Maybe someone changed it.

Comment: Take a double check if you are importing from package lombok.extern.slf4j and also you should provide version of lombok that you are using, maybe it is related to version.

Comment: Thanks, guys, those were the first things I checked after googling for this issue. What is more interesting is that Intellij correctly generates 'log'  variable, but Maven build generates 'LOGGER'.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone [configured this](https://projectlombok.org/features/log#supported-configuration-keys) in a `lombok.config` file.

You can verify this by running:

```
java -jar lombok.jar config -k lombok.log.fieldName <sourcefile.java>
```

If you want to see the full java version, you can use [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok).